# How to convert carriage returns into line breaks in php when I receive the email?

Tags: php, textarea

I have a website with form. The form is submitted to an email address so I can read it from there. I've been testing it by sending myself emails, but when I receive the message and I expect it to be like this example:

> Name: Some Guy
>
> Number: 123456789
>
> Email: someguy@someweb.com
>
> Message:
>
> Croissant liquorice macaroon. Jujubes cupcake cupcake cupcake cotton candy danish. Muffin croissant apple pie.
>
> Chupa chups jelly-o oat cake sugar plum croissant tootsie roll. Candy canes topping lemon drops. Gummies jelly gummies brownie halvah sesame snaps candy canes applicake.
>
> Marshmallow caramels sugar plum jelly macaroon sesame snaps danish powder sesame snaps. Bonbon liquorice muffin liquorice cotton candy dessert oat cake. Cotton candy caramels dessert cake pie jelly beans tiramisu. Cake applicake tiramisu muffin macaroon pie donut.

I receive them like this:

> Croissant liquorice macaroon. Jujubes cupcake cupcake cupcake cotton candy danish. Muffin croissant apple pie. Chupa chups jelly-o oat cake sugar plum croissant tootsie roll. Candy canes topping lemon drops. Gummies jelly gummies brownie halvah sesame snaps candy canes applicake. Marshmallow caramels sugar plum jelly macaroon sesame snaps danish powder sesame snaps. Bonbon liquorice muffin liquorice cotton candy dessert oat cake. Cotton candy caramels dessert cake pie jelly beans tiramisu. Cake applicake tiramisu muffin macaroon pie donut.

ALl the line breaks are gone and the message is one straight line.

I'm not yet that familiar with PHP so if you can help me in the easiest way possible it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my php comment section code:

```
<?php
//If the form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$emailText = $_POST['message'];
str_replace("\r", "\n", $emailText);

//Check to make sure that the name field is not empty
if(trim($_POST['contactname']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $name = trim($_POST['contactname']);
}

//Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted
if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {
    $hasError = true;
} else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['email']))) {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
}

//Check to make sure sure that a phone number is submitted
if(trim($_POST['phone']) == '')  {
    $hasError = true;
} else if (!preg_match("/^[1-9][0-9]{0,10}$/", trim($_POST['phone']))) {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
    $phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
}

//Check to make sure that the subject field is not empty
if(trim($_POST['subject']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
}

//Check to make sure comments were entered
if(trim($_POST['message']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
        $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
    } else {
        $comments = trim($_POST['message']);
    }
}

//If there is no error, send the email
if(!isset($hasError)) {
    $emailTo = 'myemail@gmail.com'; //Put your own email address here
    $body = "<strong>Name:</strong> $name <br><br><strong>Email:</strong> $email <br><br><strong>Contact:</strong> $phone <br><br><strong>Subject:</strong> $subject <br><br><strong>Message:</strong><br><br> $comments";
    $headers = 'From: Ucorp Online Form <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $emailSent = true;
}
 ?>
```

Comment: I am not sure if `nl2br($text)` help you or not

Comment: `nl2br()` will do the trick.

Comment: Your question is very unprecise. So it is not possible to really answer. I suggest you add more details to your question above by using the `edit` button which is offered... What do you mean by "I receive them like"? Do you output them to a browser? Do you write them to a file or send them by email? how do you visualize them? And, very important when it comes to linebreaks: what operating system are you using for your http server?

Comment: i'm not sure where to put the nl2br() since I got the php code from a free-download pre-made form but it doesn't have that functionality

Comment: @arkascha: i wanted to view them on my email. The comment/message area doesn't have the line breaks as it was originally put on the textarea.

Comment: What do you mean by "i wanted to view them on my email"? You are talking about a http server running a php script to process an incoming request. That has nothing to do with an email message. So please, once more: `edit` the question above and _add_ more details. So that we can understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Loy try adding `$comments = nl2br($comments)` at the end of your first `else`, that is just before the last `}`

Comment: @koala_dev, THANK YOU SO MUCH! This fixed my problem. How can I give you rep or something?

Comment: @LoyValera You can give him/her rep if he/she posts the comment as an answer.  Simply upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: @koala_dev You should post this as an answer.

Comment: Guys I can't see a link to upvote or post as an answer. Where is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php). Apply it after setting the value to `$comments`:

```
if(trim($_POST['message']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
        $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
    } else {
        $comments = trim($_POST['message']);
    }
    $comments = nl2br($comments);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try php's `str_replace() method.

```
$emailText = $_POST['message'];
str_replace("\r", "\n", $emailText);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php